# Какие инструменты использовать для создания фоторедактора js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

Необходимо сделать на сайте редактор изображений (типа photoshop) с основными функциями (ластик, откат, рисование, добавление изображений и пр.) Попытался реализовать на  canvas в 2д контексте, но по всем туториалам дальше рисования кругов и линий дело не идет, в документации решения тоже не нашел, даже на начальном этапе упираюсь в реализацию ластика. Уже начинаю сомневаться, что канвас подойдет для этих целей. Может быть есть другие инструменты? Или стоит капать дальше в канвас, возможно в  webGL контекст?

Comment: А в чём проблема реализовать ластик? Просто покрасьте фон в белый, а ластик пусть закрашивает область на который находится мышь белым.

Comment: Откат делается просто, нужно на каждом изменении сохранять изображение канваса, а дальше уже его подставлять когда идёт комбинация Ctrl+Z, а изображение можно создать и загрузить в канвас специальным классом, кучу туториалов по загрузке изображений в канвас есть.

Comment: Закрашивание белым не очень хорошо подходит, т.к. на выходе хочется получить png с пустыми участками а не jpg с белыми пятнами

Comment: Все это можно реализовать. Но что именно вы хотите получить в ответе? Полный готовый редактор? Поставьте конкретный вопрос. Дайте изображение и попросите реализовать функцию ластика с разными радиусами, чтобы затертое стало прозрачным.